# this.$forceUpdate equivalent in Vue 3 - Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In Vue 2, instance method `this.$forceUpdate()` could be used to update the component manually. How can we force update component in Vue 3 - Composition API (inside setup method) ?

```
setup(props, context) {
   const doSomething = () => {
     /* how to call $forceUpdate here? */
   }

   return {
       doSomething
   }
}
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$forceUpdate` is still available in Vue3, but you won't have access to it in the `setup()` function. If you absolutely need to use it, you can use object API component or this fancy trick...

```js
app.component("my-component", {
  template: `...`,
  methods: {
    forceUpdate(){
        this.$forceUpdate()
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const instance = Vue.getCurrentInstance();
    Vue.onBeforeMount(()=>{
        // instance.ctx is not populated immediately
        instance.ctx.forceUpdate();
    })
    return {doSomething};
  },
})
```

If this seems like a ridiculous solution, trust your Judgement. Ideally your application would not rely on `forceUpdate`. If you are relying on it, it *likely* means that something is miss-configured, and that should be the first thing to resolve.

Comment: I understand `forceUpdate` should be avoided by all means possible, was just curious how it's done within `setup()`. Just migrated to Vue 3 a week ago and couldn't find it in docs anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: `Property 'ctx' does not exist on type 'ComponentInternalInstance'` in Vue 3.2. Looks like it was renamed to `proxy` in this commit: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/commit/370fc820cc16c441db52d73d498cede5e851c443. 

See my answer below.

Comment: I tested with vue 3.2.0 and it still works

Comment: If you look at the commit, the `ctx` **is there**, however a Proxy for the ctx (`proxy` ) is also being added. There might be some instances where the proxy is needed for reactivity, but this doesn't seem the case. I have not seen any mention of removing `ctx` in the [release changelog](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and a change such as this would warrant more communication from the vue team.

Comment: `$forceUpdate()` is to disable Vue's incomplete reactivity (when deep nested things change, when fields are added/removed), so it can behave in a purely functional way the same way the original Snabbdom's "reactivity" behaves, on which Vue was bases, until they decided to rewrite it completely, adjusting the heavy-weight and incomplete Proxy system, after it became available in modern browsers... IMO forceUpdate is the way to "escape" Vue's reactivity.

Answer (score 30):

If using Options API:

```html
<script lang="ts">
import {getCurrentInstance, defineComponent} from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    instance?.proxy?.$forceUpdate();
  }
})
</script>
```

If using Composition API with <script setup>

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
const instance = getCurrentInstance();
instance?.proxy?.$forceUpdate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 20):

When I need to force an update in vue I usually add a key with a value I can change, which will then force vue to update it. That should work in vue 3 as well, though I admit I haven't ever tried it. Here's an example:

```html
<template>
  <ComponentToUpdate
    :key="updateKey"
  />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        updateKey: 0,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      forceUpdate() {
        this.updateKey += 1;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

You can read more about it here: https://michaelnthiessen.com/key-changing-technique/

Comment: Nice trick, thanks. I'm using vue-composition-api for vue2 and it works just fine :)

Comment: Changing the "key" property unmounts the entire DOM subtree and replaces it with another, also executing setup() on all stateful child components. Are we sure it's the best way?..

Comment: @BrianCannard: See https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: @ShadowGames I added my comment exactly explaining the consequences of following the mentioned advice.

Comment: After several hours of trying to make a reactive array that will cause an update when I modify it, I gave up and tried this old trick.  Works perfectly.  I tried using reactive() and other suggested methods.  One method worked when I added an item and one method worked when I removed an item.  Some didn't work at all.  This little hack works perfectly for me.